# How to call a REST API from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to call a Rest API from a windows service.  I have never attempted this before.  I am not sure why I am not able to make this call.

My code:

```
    string urlParameter = "posts/1";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameter).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var dataObj = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<MyType>>().Result;
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

- Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
- Inner Exception Message: {"The underlying connection was closed: The
  connection was closed unexpectedly."}
- Inner Exception Stack Trace    at
  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
  ar)

This error is being generated on the following line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameter).Result;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: (Updated Code)

```
    string urlParameter = "posts/1";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
        //var response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameter);
        var task = client.GetAsync(urlParameter);
        task.Wait();
        var response = task.Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var dataObj = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<MyType>>().Result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.Message;
        string b = ex.ToString();
    }
```

EDIT 2: (Still getting the same error)

```
private static async void TestAPI2()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Get", "application/json");

        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");

        string context = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, soz I missed the chat request earlier, sounds like you're getting there, I usually hang out in the c# chat room if you need any more help on this, pop in. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that ...

```
var response = client.GetAsync(urlParameter);
```

... returns a task, which you need to wait for it to finish first.

The cleanest way to make this call is like this ...

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameter);
```

... this requires the code be run in an async method like this ...

```
public async Task Foo() 
{
   var response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameter);
}
```

... or you can simply tell the compiler to wait using ...

```
var task = client.GetAsync(urlParameter);
task.Wait();

var response = task.Result;
```

... or a more compact version might be to use a continuation like this ...

```
var result = await client.GetAsync(urlParameter)
    .ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<MyType>>())
    .Unwrap();
```

... this will do the request then when the request comes back asyncronously parse it for you and unwrapping the task returns the "inner result" as this code creates a Task>> and you just want the IEnumerable so awaiting the unwrapped Task gets you the result of 2 tasks being executed one after another :)

... I looked at your specific code and ran that in a new console app, please update it to this ...

```
 class MyType
        {
          public int userId { get; set; }
          public int id { get; set; }
          public string title { get; set; }
          public string body { get; set; }
        }

        static void TestAnApiCall()
        {
            string urlParameter = "posts/1";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {
                //var response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameter);
                var task = client.GetAsync(urlParameter);
                task.Wait();
                var response = task.Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyType>();
                    readTask.Wait();
                    var dataObj = readTask.Result;
                    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObj));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string a = ex.Message;
                string b = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however I am still getting the same error.  In this case I went the task.Wait() route and that is where its generating the same error.  I did validate this API, I was able to call it via ajax in a separate project.  However I can't make this call from my windows service.

Comment: Hmmm ... ok if you could update the code in your question perhaps with an edit that shows the task being used correctly then details of the new exception I should be able to help you out but its hard to say without seeing the actual code you are stuck with. I know my answer works as I do this kind of thing all the time.

Comment: ok found several issues ... See updated answer, that works perfectly for me, looks like you wern't waiting on the second task and you were trying to read a collection when you only had 1 item to read

Comment: Yes, it does work in a "console app", however the same code does not work in a window service.

Comment: Check my code against yours ... I ran it perfectly fine and even packaged it up in to a windows service to be sure in the end ... my last code sample works, I tested it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111023/discussion-between-jds-and-darth-wardy).

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I think its permission related.

Comment: @PrivateJoker were you able to get to the root of the problem? I have a similar situation that a REST call works from a console app but when the client is instatiated in the Windows Service it doesn't work. I don't use the async tasks but call either `Wait()` or `Result` on them to execute synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it does work in a "console app", however the same code does not work in a window service. – John Doe**

Would like to reply on this comment. I did faced the similar issue . Rest API failed to make call from windows service but it worked from console Application.
shown as

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 80.228.241.59:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

It all happened for me due to firewall issue. And finally able to resolve this using the proxy settings in RestClient and it worked.

Comment: Could you explain how to configure the proxy settings in RestClient ?